# Methodical usage of many SQL-files in oracle-sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a lot of SQL-files which I have to use again and again - in common in a defined order:

- check something with a.sql
- update something with b.sql
- check another stuff with c.sql
- ....

I'm looking for an extension or a 3rd party or a solution to handle this methodically and comfortable sqldeveloper. My knowledge is limited, so I don't can create DLL or packages or Java-solutions .. - I need a "simple and stupid" solution ..

Are there any ideas / solutions for this?
(Maybe an expanded and structured menu? But [this](https://github.com/PhilippSalvisberg/sqldev/blob/main/workshop/060_extend_menubar/README.md#extend-menubar) doesn't looks that simple ..)

Comment: so have a master sql that calls the other sql files.

Comment: Look into PL/SQL and creating procedures

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but it seems that my question headed you to the wrong direction. Sorry.

I meant a kind of GUI or "control centre" or "integrated checklist" where I see what I have to do and in which order (and if I already did it..)

- Make step A with tool X
- When step A is done and all problems are fixed, make step B with tool Y.
- .....

Of course, the most easy way would be to write a checklist in a Text-software (Word, ..) and to call every step manually. But I'm searching for an "Integrated way".

But I'm aware that my chances for a solution are low ...

Answer (score 1):

What you described looks like a good candidate for a **package** with number of functions/procedures that are currently contained in those .SQL files.

You could put code from every file into its own procedure, and create one "master" procedure which would call them in certain order. Something like this:

Package specification contains list of all functions/procedures:

```
create or replace package pkg_test as
  procedure main;
  function a return boolean;
  procedure b;
  procedure c;
end pkg_test;
/
```

Package body contains those functions/procedures:

```
create or replace package body pkg_test as
  procedure main is
  begin
    if a then  -- if someone was hired today execute procedure B
       b;
    else
       c;      -- else, execute procedure C
    end if;
  end main;

  function a return boolean
  is
    l_cnt number;
  begin
    -- are there any employees hired today?
    select count(*)
      into l_cnt
      from emp
      where hiredate = trunc(sysdate);

    return l_cnt > 0;  -- return TRUE if someone was hired today
  end a;

  procedure b is
  begin
    insert into log_emp (datum, flag) values (trunc(sysdate), 'Y');
  end b;

  procedure c is
  begin
    update log_emp set 
      flag = 'N'
      where datum = trunc(sysdate) - 1;
  end c;
end pkg_test;
/
```

Finally, you'd just call

```
begin
  pkg_test.main;
end;
/
```

every day and let it work. Certainly, you could/should improve that simple code I composed for illustration purposes - add logging, exception handling, whatever. What's even better, you could even **schedule** that procedure to run automatically at desired time (for example, at 2 o'clock in the morning) and you'd just review what's being done in the morning.

From my point of view, that's a better option than running number of .SQL files manually.

Answer (score 0):

An Oracle SQL Developer worksheet can act as a control center for running and tracking database-centric workflows. I often use a combination of the below features to run semi-automated workflows.

1. **Worksheet -** You may have learned some bad habits from old DBAs who only ever run one simple script at a time and ignore the last few decades of UI improvements. Worksheets should be collections of many different kinds of statements that are easily run, modified, and displayed in multiple ways. Instead of just pressing Run Script (F5)
   to run the whole file, press Run Statement (Ctrl + Enter) to run the statement at the cursor.
2. **Variables -** There are many ways to set variables at the beginning of the worksheet or to set variables to the output of statements. You can use `&`, `&&`, `:`, or store variables as ad-hoc views, tables, private temporary tables, contexts, package variables, etc.
3. **SQL Statements -** (Obviously)
4. **host -** The `host` command lets you run local scripts directly through SQL Developer. For example, try highlighting and pressing Run Script (F5) for either `host dir` or `host ls`.
5. **Anonymous blocks -** If you can't create permanent objects, or just don't want to pollute your schema, wrap SQL and PL/SQL commands in an anonymous block. For example, `begin dbms_output.put_line('test'); end;` Don't forget to enable DBMS_OUTPUT in the IDE first (Views --> Dbms Output). And of course you can use these blocks to call any packages, procedures, functions, etc.
6. **@ -** Use the `@` command to run other SQL scripts.
7. **DBMS_SCHEDULER -** Use the scheduler to run things now, later, or periodically. You can also use the scheduler to run shell scripts on the database server. Running shell scripts and operating system commands through the scheduler is trickier than running them natively, but it lets you run and track your logic all in one place without logging on to the server.
8. **File management -** Put your worksheets and scripts in a local directory and control them with the "Files" window (View --> Files). Files can also be accessed through version control (although I haven't done this).

SQL Developer worksheets aren't as pretty as a more modern notebook interface, but it's still a powerful tool.